# Fixed Positioning breaking z-index

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage that I need to modify, the background, which is currently absolute positioned with z-index to push it back, needs to stay put when scrolling, i need to change it to fixed, yet doing so seems to break z-index and push the content below it vertically.  Any ideas?

edit:
OK I managed to get it to work in FF, but IE is still broken...

Comment: Have you some code or a link we can see?

Comment: first off what z-index is it currently? and why not just set the background as a background-image of the body?

Comment: .MainBG_Gradiant_Top
{
 float:left; 
 width:100%;
 top:500px;
 left:0px;
 z-index:-1; 
 height:90%;
 position:absolute; 
 background-image:url('/images/portal/BodyGradiant.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

Comment: There is already a background image, this one should be going across the bottom of the page and staying there when scrolling.

Comment: im trying to do something like this: http://www.quebecregion.com

Answer (score 6):

Maybe look at the rules below for how elements are stacked.
[The Stacking order and stacking context rules below are from this link](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

## Stacking Order within a Stacking Context

The order of elements:

1. The stacking context’s root element (the `<html>` element is the only stacking context by default, but any element can be a root element for a stacking context, see rules below)

   - **You cannot put a child element behind a root stacking context element**
2. Positioned elements (and their children) with negative z-index values (higher values are stacked in front of lower values; elements with the same value are stacked according to appearance in the HTML)
3. Non-positioned elements (ordered by appearance in the HTML)
4. Positioned elements (and their children) with a z-index value of auto (ordered by appearance in the HTML)
5. Positioned elements (and their children) with positive z-index values (higher values are stacked in front of lower values; elements with the same value are stacked according to appearance in the HTML)

## When a Stacking Context is Formed

- When an element is the root element of a document (the `<html>` element)
- When an element has a position value other than static **and** a z-index value other than auto
- When an element has an opacity value less than 1
- Several newer CSS properties also create stacking contexts. These include: transforms, filters, css-regions, paged media, and possibly others. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context
- As a general rule, it seems that if a CSS property requires rendering in an offscreen context, it must create a new stacking context.

Answer (score 2):

[Made a quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/XEwBm/). In its simplest form `z-index` doesn't break when using `position: fixed;`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can put the background that is already there in a wrapper for the whole page and use the gradient background on the body instead.

Depending on the gradient, you can also try using a css3 gradient on the background of the body (or simply multiple backgrounds...) and use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background) to make it work in IE.