# Getting a divs z-index to overlap a div with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how I could get the logo at the top of my page to appear on top of the curtains.

http://nuigums.tumblr.com/

The logo is within a section tag along with the rest of the content with a z-index of 2, which is required to get the footer reveal effect I want. The curtain has a z-index of 3. I tried setting the z-index of the logo div to 4 but I presume the fact that the sections styling overrides that?

I would like the logo to scroll with the content of the page also.

Thanks. :)

Comment: I guess this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the `position:relative` from the `section` element. and for the logo:

```
#logo{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    width:890px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

You will need to change properties of the `slider(top, left, z-index)`.

Answer (score 1):

div#logo needs to be outside of the section, which is already below the #curtain.

put div#logo before the section and set `position:absolute` then you should be able to see the kind of stacking you want.

Answer (score 0):

One line missing:

```
position:relative;
```

You can only adjust z-index if you specify position.