# Fixed Div - content is scrolling behing

Tags: css, html, fixed

I have this table at the top of my page...

```
<table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position:fixed; z-index:99999;">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" width="282" height="41" /></a></td>
    <td align="right">Hello <?php echo $_SESSION["forename"]; ?> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

it always stays at the top of the page however when scrolling down, all the content on the page goes behind the table and you can see it behind

does anyone know what i can do to stop this from happening?

EDIT:
This is my full code...

```
<style type="text/css">
body,html {
    height:100%;
}
#top-bar {
    width:100%;
    padding:10px 10px 80px 10px;
    margin:0 0 100px 0;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #000000;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#left-bar {
    width:170px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
#right-bar {
    width:80%;
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="top-bar">
<table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" width="282" height="41" /></a></td>
    <td align="right">Hello <?php echo $_SESSION["forename"]; ?> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="left-bar"><iframe src="header.php" width="180px" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>

<div id="right-bar">
<iframe name="rightiframe" src="dash.php" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: look at the style you are using style="position:fixed; z-index:99999;"

Comment: possible duplicate of [z-index not working with fixed positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning)

Answer (score 1):

You're most probably looking for this:

```
<table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position:fixed;z-index:999;top:0;left:0;background-color:#fff">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" width="282" height="41" /></a></td>
    <td align="right">Hello <?php echo $_SESSION["forename"]; ?> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `background-color` makes sure you can't see any content that is behind the table.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CRHxk/

Comment: i want the table to stay at the top of the page and not move when scrolling

Comment: but thats still going to push the table where you cant see it when scrolling?