# Position absolute has greater z-index than position fixed

Tags: css

I have a poblem with an element that is positioned relative. The problem is that I have a header with position fixed and content which is positioned relative. If I scroll down the content the element is put in front of the header. I tried with z-index but I just can't get it to work. I have put `z-index:999` on header.

Here you can see my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUW66/)

Here is a picture:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can find the answer [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5218927/1313143)?

Comment: set z-index on both, fixed and relative.

Comment: In `position:fixed` i gave `z-index:9999` nad in `relative` `z-index:1`

Comment: You did? We need to see some code then. Edit your question with the html and css please.

Comment: Ok I edited my question with a jsFiddle

Comment: Beautiful screenshots :D ... i have nothing more to add

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `z-index` on the relative positioned element should be lower than the `z-index` on the fixed position element.  Here is a quick example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixed">Fixed Position</div>
<div id="relative">Relative Position</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    height: 3000px;
}

#fixed{
    top: 0;
    height; 100px;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}

#relative{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/XZ4tM/1/

### Fixing Your Example

The header styling has an issue, there are two colons `::` proceeding the z-index properties value.

```
  .header{
        width:960px;
        background: #43484A;
        height:80px;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        z-index: 9999; /* Removed extra : here */
   }
```

**Fixed Example** http://jsfiddle.net/kUW66/2/

Answer (score 2):

What I think you did is correct that using z-index in only a option. I have some work for you to understand.

Please follow the [JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sanman/nZfHs/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content1"><div id="content2"></div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin:0px auto;
    color:#FFF;
}
#header{
    background-color:#006666;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    font:bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:50px;
    display:block;
    z-index:10;
}
#content1{
    width:70%;
    height:1200px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color:#FFFF66;
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    z-index:9;

}
#content2{
    width:50px;
    height:250px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color:#F60;
    postition:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not how you post code with a jsFiddle link. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

"Content" is relative to the window, not the grey square.

Did you try to make that grey square `position:relative`?

Without the HTML and the CSS, it's really hard to know the real cause.

Answer (score -1):

```
   .categories li{
        position:relative;
        z-index:-1;
        list-style: none;
        float:left;
        width:310px;
        height:310px;
        color:white;
        background:#77647F;
        margin-right:10px;
   }
```

check this fiddle :)[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/kUW66/1/)

I have changed the z-index to -1 to make it work.

Comment: Note that using a negative z-index tends to make content unclickable, which is problematic in many situations.