# How does z-index and position fixed work together in css

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.fixed h3 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="fixed">
  <center>
    <h3>
      Only this thing should be brought on top of overlay..
    </h3>
  </center>
</div>
```

Now how do I place get the h3 inside the .fixed div on top of overlay. Please post some reading on fixed along with z-index.

http://jsfiddle.net/CvMLw/4/
Check the above jsfiddle, So how do i bring the h3 on top of overlay..

Comment: possible duplicate of [z-index not working with fixed positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning)

Comment: Please tell me you're not doing page layout with br tags. If you're using more than two, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: you are combining 2 positions `absolute` and `fixed` for the same element `.overlay`

Comment: @fotanus - I'm rolling on the floor!

Comment: @blachawk I just couldn't focus in this question

Comment: @fotanus same here...the <br> package is more visible than any other code on here.

Answer (score 10):

You set a `z-index` on an element inside a fixed `div` that is under the overlay.

In other words, the overlay hiding the `z-index` value is 301.

You see, it's like lego blocks. `.fixed` is at the bottom with its z-index at 0.

Then on `.fixed` your `h3` is 300 blocks one over another.

If we add, for example, another `div` below the `h3` tag with `z-index` of 150, the "tower of blocks" would be lower than the `h3` so `h3` would be on the top.

Then there is another `div`(`.overlay`) on the same DOM level as `.fixed` with a higher `z-index` than `.fixed`. This block would placed right over the 300 blocks of `h3`.

For example:

```
<==============================>   <- the .overlay (z-index 1)
            <=>
            <=>
            <=>
            <=>
  <=>       <=>                <- Elements inside .fixed (random z-index)
  <=>       <=>
  <=>       <=>
  <=>       <=>
  <=>       <=>
<==============================>    <- the .fixed (z-index 0)
```

To set the h3 on top, put it on the same lvl of your overlay or set a higher `.fixed` `z-index`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that if `.fixed` element is acting as a *holder* for any of its children.

This means that if, for example, you set your `h3` with an absolute position to the bottom, it will go **to the bottom of its parent element**.

`z-index` works the same way. Its value will be inherited by the parent. Since the `z-index` default value is `0`, your `.fixed` element has a `z-index` value of `0`, and your `h3` has *first* `0` and then `300`.

Answer (score -7):

Change your

```
position:fixed;
```

to

```
position:absolute;
```

on `.fixed`, then it works.