# Z-Index and Sticky Element

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, sticky

I have a sticky header on my website and a *Jquery Zooming* effect on the products.

This two elements are in conflict actually, the zooming effect goes over the sticky header.

I tried to reduce the `Z-index` of the Zooming effect but nothing.

Here the link : http://www.directportes.fr/luxe-1

I used a script to make the sticky element :

https://gist.github.com/johnnyopao/896e042fe7daac49d119

I used another script for the zooming effect :

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.zoomElevate').elevateZoom({
    zoomType    : "lens", lensShape : "round", lensSize : 200
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide code extracts instead of a link, so that we don't have to work ourselves through a dictionary of code

Comment: Yeah, if you could actually post code, versus an entire website for us to debug that would be helpful, and make it a lot more likely for people to help.

Comment: (please read [this section of the Stack Overflow help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Yes sorry I edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked it and i saw that you are trying to use z-index with position fixed. Check this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362113/how-does-z-index-and-position-fixed-work-together-in-css) question to understand more for that and how to fix

Comment: Thanks for help, I'll check this now

Comment: It's ok. It would be great if you would just get your header and an image code and create a jsfiddle or a code snippet here so we could try something on it :)

Comment: After lot of research, it's seem there is conflict between this two property.

Actually, I've changed the design. Thanks for help, I close the question.