# Z-index works in FF, not in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, position, z-index

I have two divs, one with the z-index set individually by ID, the other with z-index set by its class...
The div with z-index set in its class does not stack as expected in Chrome 27 (Windows 7)...it works well in Firefox 21.

Here is the CSS:

```
.subMenuClass{
display: none;
float: right;
z-index: 1000;
position:relative;
padding: 20px 40px 20px 20px;
width: 200px;
height: 600px;
} (doesn't work in Chrome)

#theme_Div{
width: 220px;
height: 600 px;
z-index: 10000;
position:absolute;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 60px;
} (works in Chrome)
```

HTML is simply:

```
<div id="theme_Div" class="mainMenuClass">
<div id="subMenu" class="subMenuClass">
```

Ideas? I have several dozen of these 'subMenus' and would rather not have to create a CSS rule for each one individually.

Sorry, I left out something important...you see above the subMenu class is set to :display:none...the display changes to 'inline' upon a click of a button in the 'theme_div'... in any case, this code works fine in Firefox...

Comment: Please include your HTML code and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), if possible.

Comment: I added the HTML, there isn't much there...A JSfiddle would be difficult b/c this app is internal and uses internal map services.  I am hoping this may be something simple that I overlooked?

Comment: The `z-index` definitions work for me in Chrome 27.0.1453.110 Mac. http://jsfiddle.net/sFZpU/1/

Comment: this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning

Comment: I notice when I change the position on the subMenu to 'absolute'..it stacks on top of the 'theme_div" (and also does not 'float:right')..?

Comment: I added something important to my question above...I should mention also I am using JQuery to change the display attribute.

Comment: Can you add mainMenuClass ?

Answer (score 0):

well this seems to work in both Firefox and Chrome..maybe someone can explain to me why!

```
.subMenuClass{
display: none;
/*float: right;*/
right: 0;
z-index: 10000;
position:absolute;
padding: 20px 40px 20px 20px;
width: 200px;
height: 600 px;
```

}

```
#theme_Div{
width: 220px;
height: 600 px;
z-index: 10000;
display:inline;
position:absolute;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 60px;
```

}

The big change was changing the position of the subMenu to 'absolute', and replacing 'float:right' with 'right: 0' ... the absolute positioning seems counter-intuitive to me....but it works!