# Z-index for Position: fixed

Tags: html, visual-web-developer

So I am in the process of making a webpage. I need to use Z-Index so I can have some cool effects and such. I have come to the point where I need to make a fixed navigation bar and use Z-Index: 2(for example)Is there any equivalent to Z-index while using position: fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning)

Comment: What problem are you having? Z-index should work on elements with `position: fixed`.

Comment: It looks like setting position to relative on the other elements may help.

Comment: This is not the case. In that question it looks like the person div positions and styles were creating the problem. I'm wondering if there are any equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

Z-index applies to any object with a position value, whether it is fixed, absolute or relative. If you've applied a position value (in this case fixed) to your object, then z-indexing should behave as it does with any other positioned object.

If you are having a specific problem, you'd need to elaborate more in your question.

Comment: Hmm, Ill have to look at my code more.

Comment: Turns out that one of my scripts was screwing with the Z-index of another element and I had put in the wrong layer causing it to appear to not work. My fault :).

Comment: Something you may be having trouble with, objects with no position applied will sometimes overlap z-index'ed objects. If you have objects you want to go behind your fixed object, give them position:relative (don't necessarily need a z-index too) and that should allow them to fall into place behind higher indexed objects.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/fixed-position-z-index

According to the above mentioned article we can use `z-index` with fixed positioning!