# Z-index not working with position fixed

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I am trying to add some overlay instruction via chardinjs to my website.  I have a fixed navbar with an image.  I want the overlay to look as it looks on the [chardinjs](http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/) page.  Here is my html:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container navbar-container">
        <a class="brand" href="/web/Home"><img src="assets/header-logo2.gif" data-intro="Click logo to return to main portal" data-position="bottom" class=" chardinjs-show-element chardinjs-relative-position"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This site is built using Bootstrap, so all of the classes are inline with basic Bootstrap.  My navbar is fixed to the top of the page with `position: fixed` and the z-index is `1030`.  The `navbar-inner`, `container` and `brand` have no listed z-index or position.  The `img` has `position: relative` and `z-indez: 9999999`.  The only way to make the image show above the overlay is to set the navbar to `position: relative` and remove the z-index.  I dont want my navbar moving, but more importantly, I want to know why.  Any help this issue will be great.

Comment: That is not a helpful question title.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [z-index not working with fixed positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning?rq=1)

"z-index only works within a particular context i.e. relative, fixed or absolute position.

z-index for a relative div has nothing to do with the z-index of an absolutely or fixed div."
@cusimar9