# How to overlap a div's border on top of another one below it?

Tags: css

I have an element that has a bottom border and it I would like to show it on top of an image, however, when I move the relevant div down (using negative bottom margin) the border goes under an image element that is underneath. Is there a way to set it on top?

I tried z-index but to no avail. And I have to have the "top" div have the border.

```
<div class="top">One</div>
<div class="block"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></div>
.top {border-bottom:5px solid red; margin-bottom:-3px; z-index:5;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gdRWy/1/

Image hosted by Placekitten and taken by: [Pieter Lanser](http://www.flickr.com/people/35652310@N00)

Thanks guys

Comment: position:relative; itself would do it, and triggers z-index if really needed

Comment: FWIW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gdRWy/3/

```
position:relative; /* this is enough */
```

See my earlier comment

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="top">One</div>
<div class="block"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></div>
.top {border-bottom:5px solid red; margin-bottom:-3px; z-index:5; position:relative;}
```