# z-index is not working with position fixed

Tags: css

I've something like the following css:

```
#one{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
#two{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
#link{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999999; /*this is not in higher layer why??? */
}
```

**I cannot increase the z-index of `#two` as per my design.**

But I've assigned higher z-index to the `#link` but it's not getting in higher layer.

So, why the position fixed is blocking to the layer (z-index) ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0q84xq87/)

If the position of #one wasn't positioned fixed then it would work fine. So, my question is why position fixed is giving me a bug?

Comment: @Dwza there is a fiddle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [z-index not working with fixed positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why the position fixed is blocking to the layer (z-index) ?

This is because of [The stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html). CSS positioning and adding a `z-index` value to an element creates a new stacking context.

From [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context):

> **Note:** The hierarchy of stacking contexts is **a subset of the hierarchy of HTML elements**.

Hence in your particular case:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <a href="#" id="link">test</a>
</div>
```

The hierarchy of stacking contexts would be:

- Root

  - `#one`
  - `#two`

    - `#link`

And `#link` would be placed under the `#one` no matter how much its `z-index` value is.

One option is increasing the `z-index` value of `#two` element (more than `#one`).

Comment: @C-linkNepal `fixed` positioning is not the case: http://jsfiddle.net/0q84xq87/2/ But the order of HTML elements are placed in DOM. If you use `relative` positioning for `#one` the computed height and width would be 0 because it doesn't have any contents: http://jsfiddle.net/0q84xq87/3/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the link hover #two?
something like that?

```
#one{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#two{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
#link{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0q84xq87/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `z-index` to wrapper `div`

```
#two{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#link{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I've claimed with bold text that I cannot increase the z-index of #two as per my design...

Comment: `z-index` only works with same layer elements. In above case it works only with `#one` and `#two`. If you cant increase the `z-index` of `#two` then you can add separate wrapper for link which has greater `z-index` than `#one`

Answer (score 0):

Because `#link`'s `z-index` is relative to `#two`'s (which is `#link`'s parent) `z-index` then `#one`'s and `#two`'s `z-index` are relative to their parent(in this case `body`).