# JS/JQuery: Can't trigger an event associated with an element that is above another element

Tags: events, click, overlay, element

I have an element, `#i1`, that is below another element, `.close_button`, and they each have a click event associated with them...the former's is called `clickFade()` while the latter's event is a anonymous function that is defined within the execution of the aforementioned `clickFade()`.

When `clickFade()` is called by clicking on `#i1`, the parent div,`#welcome`, is fadedTo opacity .1 and `#A` is fadedIn. Also, `unbind()` is called for `#i1` and the anonymous function mentioned above that is associated with a click event on `.close_button` is defined. This function just reverses the effects that `clickFade()` has when a close_button image is clicked.

I don't think the problem is a z-index issue (because I've tried it already and the close_button image is always visible on top). I also don't think it's a binding issue because the button works, but only when there's nothing underneath of it...for example, if the button is half overlapping one of the background images like `#i1`, the half that isn't on top of `#i1` will trigger the event while the other half will not.

What's the problem here and how can I fix it?

Here are the gists for the [HTML](https://gist.github.com/Aweeeezy/887f45e15bdf6cd1d495), [CSS](https://gist.github.com/Aweeeezy/b16ea21daf072b8f8f52), and [JS](https://gist.github.com/Aweeeezy/0ca928195a21f1058e3c); here's the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<div id="welcome">
    <p id="welcomeText">Welcome</p>
    <img src="imgs/img1.jpg" id="i1" alt=null/>
</div>
```

---

```
<div id="A">
    <img src='imgs/close_button.gif' class='close_button' alt=null
    style="width: 10%; height: 10%"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function clickFade() {
    $('#welcome').fadeTo('slow',.1);
    $('#i1').unbind('click',clickFade);
    $('#i1').unbind('mouseover',mouseOverFunc);
    switch (this.id) {
        case "i1":
            $('#A').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.close_button').click(function() {
                $('#A').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#welcome').fadeTo('slow',1);
                $('#i1,#i3,#i5').click(clickFade).mouseover(mouseOverFunc);
            });
            break;
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you both have to set the z-index AND set position:relative for this to work.

[z-index not working with fixed positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning) and others.  Good luck!

Comment: This did it. So the reason it did not work is not because my `#welcome` div had a `position: absolute;`, but because my `.close_button` image did not have a set `position`?

Comment: Yes, everything involved has to have position:relative or there's no z-order.  Makes sense if you think about it...