# Positioning of two divs

Tags: html, css

i have got 2 divs

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
#first
{
float:left;
width: 150px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;

}
#second
{
float:left;
width: 1000px;
height: 100%;
}
```

when i zoom in page and scroll it right. 1st div will be above 2nd. How can i keep it fixed but not let it get above other divs?; (i want to make it fixed for scroll up/down, but not left/right)

Comment: I don't get your idea. You are making the div fixed, but you don't want it to be fixed... Please provide more information.

Comment: Note that `float` has no effect on fixed elements

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find your answer within this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zoc053dh/

And for a detailed explanation see this link: [z-index not working with fixed positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning)

You are having trouble understanding the principles of position (relative, fixed, absolute etc.) and z-index.

Cheers, 
Please mark this answer as correct if this is the answer you were looking for.