# Bootstrap Carousel Controls Not Click Able On setting z-index to -1

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/cLKQZEjCWO) and let me know how I can enable ht e controls o the Bootstrap Carousel when I have to set z-index like -1?

```
#test{z-index:-1;}
.box1{height:500px; background-color:red;}
.box2{height:500px; background-color:blue;}

<section class="navbar-fixed-top" id="test">
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>

  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/bg-1-full.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/bg-2-full.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </section>
<section>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>
<section>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `section#test` is set to `position: fixed` which means not only that it stays at the same position, but also that it doesn't take up any space. That is why the next `section` is at the same position as `section#test`. Now, since you set `section#test` to `z-index: -1`, the other `section` is in front of `section#test`. Therefore you can't click the controls.

The solution is to remove `position: fixed` from `section#test`. In your case, the best thing to do is to simply remove the class `navbar-fixed-top` from `section#test`. Additionally, you should disable your script, so the sections are next to each other.

http://www.bootply.com/rAx64sK7wd

Comment: Thanks Simon but as I said I need to keep the section test fixed.

Comment: You didn't say that in your post, but I can help you out.
Why do you need it fixed? What is your goal?

Comment: What I want to get is something like this BUT with a bootstrap slider as I have

Comment: As you an see the slider and layout works fine BUT the slider controlls are not working!

Comment: There was a similar question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning