# Not able to use modal in parent element with position as fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi am try to use bootstrap modal inside of fixed positioned parent element.
But seems like its not working as expected.
Here is an example,

```
<div class="fixed">
  <div>
    <div>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMPOpo

**Note: I would like to keep my HTML structure as it is.**

Comment: Why do you need to use `position:fixed`?

Comment: Because parent element needs to have position as fixed.

Comment: I got it working with same HTML structure and little different CSS.


https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMPOpo

Answer (score 3):

You just have to lower the z-index of backdrop of modal,

Try this simple CSS and you are good to go

```
.modal-backdrop{
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the issue? it's not clickable?

Trying setting the modal to position:relative and give it a z-index.

See here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJPWdr

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Remove `fixed` class

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvZXVG

Here, a question with the same issue: [z-index not working with fixed positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning#5219023)

or MDN documentation: [The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: I have to use fixed parent element,
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMPOpo, this is the solution I got.

Comment: The `button` looks overlapped and it is above the backdrop. If the fixed parent is so important, well then.