# Why modal-backdrop overlapped my popup modal even set !important and z-index? How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

I had a successful message popup. Now I want to add a semi-transparent backdrop layer underneath with `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`, that I used `CSS ::before`. But the backdrop `::before { rgba(0,0,0,0.5) }` seems to overlap my green popup, even when I set `z-index` and `background: !important` for the popup.

Here's the code I've tried

```css
.alertMessageModal{ width:auto; height:auto; border-radius:10px; display:inline-block; position:fixed; top:20px; right:25px; color:#fff; padding:10px 15px; padding-bottom:15px; z-index:100; background:green !important;}
.alertMessageModal::before{content:''; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); z-index:-100;}
.alertMessageModal .modal-title{ font-size:15px; float:left; line-height:18px;}
.alertMessageModal .close{ float:right; margin-left:10px; line-height: 15px; color:#fff;}
```

```html
<div class="alertMessageModal bg-success">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Your message has been successfully sent</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: i want to UP green background. down transparent background.

Comment: So what attempts have you made? This should be simple

Comment: how can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the modal's content inside another extra wrapper div `.modal-content`. The [example from w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp).

Your code doesn't work as expected because [z index not working with fixed positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning)

Here's the working code, I changed a few lines of code from yours:

```css
/* renamed from .alertMessageModel::before */
.alertMessageModal {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -100;
}
/* renamed from .alertMessageModal */
.modal-content {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
  background: green !important;
}
.alertMessageModal .modal-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.alertMessageModal .close {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="alertMessageModal bg-success">

  <!-- added an extra div -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Your message has been successfully sent</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Loi Nguyen Huynh