# How to fix bootstrap navbar to top with sidebar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am developing a page in which I have both `sidebar` as well as `navbar` I have to make my navbar fix to the top so that it is a better user experience.

**Issue**

But when  I am using inbuilt `fixed-top` bootstrap class it is overriding the sidebar, my `navbar` starts after the width of sidebar,

So I just want to make that fixed at the top so that scrolling becomes easier

**My navbar code**

```
<div>
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" className="py-3 navbar_style">
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto"></Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Link href="#deets">Logout</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    </div>
```

**Side bar CSS**

```
.sidebar {
height: 100%;
width: 100px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
transition: all 0.6s;
background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
opacity: 1;
```

}

[Working code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-dhawan-z6veb?file=/src/styles.css)

I have written the minimal code in sandbox, I just want to fix navbar to the top without overriding my sidebar, please check the code sandbox

Comment: So you want to fix the nav bar at the top of the screen, but beneath the sidebar? Am I understanding your question correctly? Why can't you just do position: fixed, zIndex: 0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [z-index not working with fixed positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning)

Answer (score 0):

```
Navbar{
  z-index: 1000;
}
.sidebar {
  z-index: 500;
}
```

it will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this should do it:

```
.navbar_style{
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: nop it is overriding the sidebar, you can check the code

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "overriding the sidebar". Do you want the navbar to be below or above the sidebar?

Comment: If you want it below the sidebar then change z index to 0 @manish

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the position of the header nav is overlapping the sidebar nav - this is because both items are `fixed`. After you add `fixed-top` to your navbar you will need to use `margin-top` on your sidebar to add a buffer and push your sidebar down. Example;

```
.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 233px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 500;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    background: rgb(167, 144, 144);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #e0cccc29;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 72px; /**<--add this**/
}
```

You have to adjust this to whatever the size of your top navbar is. Using inspect I can see it is `72px` so I set `margin-top` of your sidebar to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

**Change positions**

`position:sticky` to **sidebar**

```
.sidebar {
 position: sticky;
}
```

`position:fixed` to **navbar_style**

```
.navbar_style {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add

> sticky-top

class on both your sidebar and navbar class

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.